# Doctrine Error on attempting to retrieve a boolean value - line 0, col 111: Error: Expected end of string, got '1'

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I am attempting to retrieve a boolean value in doctrine query. I can successfully retrieve a String value in the doctrine query but on adding a boolean argument of variable name active from my Entity class I got an error

```
[Syntax Error] line 0, col 111: Error: Expected end of string, got '1'
```

complete doctrine snippet

```
$results = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('RealBundle:Cats')
                ->createQueryBuilder('q')
                ->addSelect('ABS(q.pts) AS HIDDEN pointsOrder') 
                ->orderBy('pointsOrder', 'DESC')
                ->orderBy('active', TRUE) //code fails at this point
                ->getQuery()
                ->getResult();
```

Please what could I be doing drong

Comment: `TRUE` doesn't look like it belongs into an ORDER BY clause.

Comment: `ABS(q.pts) AS HIDDEN pointsOrder` whats this? two aliases?

Comment: on removing the True parameter everything is fine and I needed to OrdeyBy using the active variable @RaymondNijland

Comment: is HIDDEN some Doctrine keyword then?

Answer (score 1):

try to change to this:

```
$results = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('RealBundle:Cats')
                ->createQueryBuilder('q')
                ->addSelect('ABS(q.pts) AS HIDDEN pointsOrder') 
                ->addOrderBy('pointsOrder', 'DESC')
                ->addOrderBy('active', 'ASC') //code fails at this point
                ->getQuery()
                ->getResult();
```

You need to use `addOrderBy` to use more than one order by and second argument of `addOrderBy` need to be `ASC` or `DESC`, it can't be `TRUE`

Comment: Error active is not defined. plz note that active is a boolean value